# Is Hair loss any way related to body building?

Tags: health, health-risk

I assume the more we do body building, the more insulin, testosterone and growth hormones are utilised in bodybuilding and the less it involves in hair growth, which in turn results in hair loss. Any ways to balance it?

Pardon my ignorance and correct me if wrong.

Comment: I think a dermatologist or an ortho would be better aware of this.

Comment: You may think that because a vast majority of professional bodybuilders take anabolic steroids which have been linked to hair loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read a study once where balding men were found to have higher testosterone levels than men with a full head of hair.

People who take supplements to boost testosterone levels (like Sust 250) report an itchy scalp (it'll freakin drive you crazy, but don't ask me how I know). This has been attributed to the higher testosterone levels that are associated with those steroids.

It effects everyone different, and it depends on the dosage and frequency of these "supplements".

So, I would say hair loss is not related to body building per say, but rather to the levels of testosterone in the body. At a bodybuilding gym, there are going to be a higher percentage of people taking testosterone boosting supplements, hence there will be a higher percentage of balding men (or women) in there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that more than anything hair loss is due to genetic predisposition. Whether you are doing body building avidly or not...if you are supposed to lose hair, you will.